# Изменить язык на карте

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Проблема заключается в том, что на телефоне установлен русский язык, но на карте перемешан и русский, и украинский (я нахожусь в Украине). 
Как обойти это и сделать показ карт только на русском?

```
  private Geocoder geocoder;
  private Locale ruLocale = new 
Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").setScript("Cyrl").setRegion("RU").build();
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, ruLocale);
```

[image: Пример карты]

Comment: Приведённый пример кода не помог исправить это

Comment: [Это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30451692/3069565) пробовали?

Comment: Да, пробовал
Переводятся большие какие-то места, но вот конкретно улицы просто на английский переключаются

Comment: Возможно, что для этих мест у гугла просто нет перевода на русский.

Comment: Понял, так и подозревал, но надеялся, что это моя ошибка где-то была, спасибо)

Comment: Попробуйте применить сенсор языка в ссылке maps.googleapis : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=ru